# how to remove \n from a string in python

Tags: python

Am using the below code to create a dataframe but am getting 'Mr. \n abc \n D. \n abc' for name , i want to get rid of \n, please help

Below is my code:

```
names = []
orgs = []

for name in all_table_info.find_all('td', 
           class_="views-field views-field-field-lastname active"):
    names.append(name.text.strip() if name.text else None)

for organization in all_table_info.find_all('td', 
           class_="views-field views-field-field-employer"):
    orgs.append(organization.text.strip() if organization.text else None) 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : names, 'Org' : orgs})

print (df)
```

Thanks & Regards,
Sanjay

Comment: If you have a string just do str.strip('\n') / str.strip('\n', '')
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347419/python-strip-with-n

Comment: strip only removes leading and trailing characters, not mid-string. :/

Comment: @Uvar whoops, that was a typo. Meant to do strip('\n') and replace('\n', '')

Comment: Please `print(df.head(10))` and edit your question with the output. I'll be easier to figure out what you need.

Comment: Name            org
Mr. \n Rex \n D. \n Adams Invesco Ltd.
Mr. \n William  \n S. \n Allen Macy's Inc.
Mr. \n R. \n Wayne \n Anderson Amoco Corporation
Prof. \n Chris \n Argyris (1923-2013) Monitor Company
Marcia \n J. \n Avedon, \n Ph.D. Ingersoll Rand, plc.

Here i want to remove (Full stops and '\n')

Comment: @K.Sanjay Add it to your question, I can't understand it in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

```
mystring = "Bla \n abc \n D. \n blabla"
print(mystring.replace("\n", ""))

## Bla  abc  D.  blabla
```

That should serve your needs.

Comment: I have tried the below code but it is throwing an error                             "none type object  is not callable",                                                          here is my code                                                                                                                                                                                                                       for name in all_table_info.find_all('div', 
           class_="views-field views-field-view"):
    names.append(name.text.strip() if name.text else None)
    print(name.replace("\n", ""))

Comment: Don't name your variable `str`.

Comment: I tried like this ,print(str.replace("\n", ""))  , but is is throwing a TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: @BradSolomon you are right..I should not overwrite a class. :)

Comment: @K.Sanjay as you can see by the comma separation, it has 2 arguments. If your interpreter faults you for giving only one, you probably made a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove whitespace from the beginning and end of a string, use:

```
'  word  \n'.strip()  # -> 'word'
```

If you want to remove newlines from the middle of a word, use:

```
'a \n b \n c'.replace('\n', '')  # -> 'a  b  c'
```