# How to extract columns with commas and/or newlines from a csv using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a csv file containing multiple columns.I have written a program to extract a subset of columns from it.
here is my code:

```
import csv
filename='input.csv'
f = open(filename, 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(f,quotechar='"')
with open("output.csv","a+") as o:
    for row in reader:
        print (row[7] + "," + row[10] ,file=o)
```

the columns that I am extracting i.e column 8 and column 11 cause a few problems as they have newlines or may have commas in them.
for eg:

```
aaaa,"bbbb
bbbb"
cccc,"dd,ddd"
```

so when my program extracts these columns from input.csv it strips the quotes thus the spaces or commas that are inside the quotes are counted as new fields.
any soultions?

Comment: This thread will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347419/python-strip-with-n