# how to remove the \u and \x characters with python?

Tags: python

When I use vim to open the file, the text is shown like:

```
"<200b>blablabla ^B ewjowqwe"
```

Here, the `<200b>` is unicode `\u200b`, and `^B` is `\x02`.

I can use regular expression like:

`re.sub("\u200b|\x02", "", line)` to remove the special characters.

But now I want to remove all the characters like `\u` and `\x`,

when I use `re.sub("\u.{4}|\x.{2}", "", line)`, it will raise exception `"incomplete escape \x at position"`

How can I write the regular expression to remove all the special `\u` and `\x` characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python strip with \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347419/python-strip-with-n)

Comment: Use a raw string: `r"\u.{4}|\x.{2}"`