# Unable to remove newline from string

Tags: python

Im trying to remove a new line from a string like so:

```
jsonata_expr = r'''{
    "ips": *.*.ip_addr,
    "vlans": $join(vlans.($string(vlan_id)), ","),
    "date": $now()
}'''

jsonata_expr.strip('\n')
'{\n    "ips": *.*.ip_addr,\n    "vlans": $join(vlans.($string(vlan_id)), ","),\n    "date": $now()\n}'
```

But as you can see the newlines are still there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python strip with \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347419/python-strip-with-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strip` will work only with leading and trailing positions. So one solution is to replace newline character with empty string.

```
jsonata_expr.replace("\n", "")
```

Please note that this will produce a new string object(In python, strings are **Immutable** by design)